# When clicked on button the image is not changing for the first time. Button image is to be changed when clicked for the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
if( [[favbutton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wishlwhite.png"]])
{
    [favbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wishlistwhite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    // other statements
}
else
{
    [favbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wishlwhite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // other statements
}
```

Comment: check condition this way - `if ([favbutton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wishlwhite.png"]])`

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be checking the image in the button to determine state. Declare a separate property to test, e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isWishList; // or something

-(IBAction) toggleButton: (id) sender {

    if (self.isWishList) {
        [favbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wishlistwhite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements
    } else {
        [favbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wishlwhite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
        // other statements
    }    
    self.isWishList = !self.isWishList
}
```